# cancancan alert and notice messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

Question from a newbie with Rails.

I have this:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
 respond_to do |format|
   format.json { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
   format.html { redirect_to main_app.root_url, notice: exception.message }
   format.js   { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
 end
end
```

in application_controller.rb

I have tried several ways to add to or to replace the exception message in a specific case such as

```
  def show
    authorize! :read, @post, :alert => "Please log in to access this page"

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(4).offset(1)
  end
```

Here I use `alert` and I have no alert message displayed. Trying `notice` doesn't replace the exception message from the Cancan rescue.

I've also tried this:

```
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if can? :update, @post %>
              <p><%= link_to "modify", edit_post_path(@post.id) %></p>
            <% else %>
              <%= flash[:alert] = 'Please log in to access this page' %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
```

in my show.html.erb page, which I find less dry than my code in the post_controller.rb above.

Before I try some nice code with css ot JS, I'd like to see at least something basic happening. Where does the problem come from ?

Of course, I have these lines in my pages:

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

Comment: Oh seems like you can actually pass in `message:` into `authorize!` from [HERE](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/exception-handling)

Comment: That's where I'd seen the possibility and it looks fine, but doesn't work with me.

Comment: did you try passing in `:message` into `authorize!`? `:alert` is not supported.

Comment: afterwards, this should already work because `exception.message` is being passed into your `redirect_to main_app.root_url` as `:notice`, and you already have `<%= notice %>` in your page. If this still doesn't work, you might have been overriding the value of `flash[:notice]` somewhere.

Comment: To make sure the message is already being passed into the redirect, try  debugging by inserting `puts exception.message` just exactly below `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|`

Comment: The puts says `You are not authorized to access this page.` and that's what I want to avoid (the original execption.message). Changing `:alert' for ':notice' doesn't change anything for the time being. No I have no other use of notice anywhere else.

Comment: If I change ` :notice ` for ` :message ` int application_controller.rb nothing is being displayed, which is obvious from 'its' point of view. Because at the same time, I am trying to display ' :alert ' and ' :notice ' from the show_html.erb page and the post_controller.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing out on a new rails project, the following would make yours work:

**app/controllers/SOMECONTROLLER.rb**

```
def show
  authorize! :show, @post, message: 'Please log in to access this page'
  # and not...
  # authorize! @post, message: 'Please log in to access this page'
  # ...
end
```

Comment: You mean after adding  `add_flash_types` in the application_helper ? For the time being, I have a routing error with this.

Comment: I didn't add `add_flash_types` into `application_helper.rb`. What was the routing error? I'm guessing you are authorised so it skipped that line above, and thus perhaps the error comes from this line? `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`? If not, can you show what the routing error is?

Comment: also can you try this again:
*To make sure the message is already being passed into the redirect, try debugging by inserting puts exception.message just exactly below `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|`*

Comment: The routing error is gone after I have defined the flash_type 'message' properly in application_helper.rb but the final result is the same. And you are right: debugging shows the expected message. I just need to add the html for it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh you added a custom flash type named `:message`? that's because you have a `flash[:message]` somewhere. You don't really need a custom flash message for this unless you really intend to do so. There are only two default flash types: `:notice`, and `:alert`